# Possible ways to detect where 'undefined' is being overwritten?

Tags: javascript, debugging, undefined

I currently have a bug in IE7 where undefined being overwritten causes the website to crash. It works fine on Firefox, Chrome and IE8+ (I'm guessing because those browsers don't allow undefined to be overwritten).

I'm trying to find where it is being done, to be able to protect my code. Unfortunately, it's not on my own code. I tried looking for "undefined=", "undefined =" and "['undefined']" in firebug, in the hope that I'd find which dependency is changing overwriting it, unsuccessfully.

I am stuck now, and I really don't know what else to try. Does anyone has an idea what I could do to find the line of code responsible for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not a direct answer, but did you try protecting your code with the self-calling anonymous function pattern `(function(undefined) {})()`?

Comment: I do not believe it is possible to detect assignment changes to undefined (however, can a property setter be established for `window.undefined`?), although, perhaps put in a log after each external script that is loaded, to see if that can identify the problem. Also, perhaps a "watch expression".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never be using `undefined` as if it were a value anyway. The correct way to test for undefined-ness is `typeof somevar == "undefined"`

Comment: I disagree with this. This is like saying one should *not* rely on True or False being predictable values in Python (2.x) because they can be re-assigned. My viewpoint: **any code that alters the value of `undefined` is broken** - it breaks the contract that is expected, and that is all programming is. Thus, in any environment that *my* code is expected to run, `undefined === void(0)` had better be true. (Not that I use `undefined` often; also, why not `x === void(0)` for a comparission?)

Comment: Note that if you want to pass JSLint it will insist on comparing directly to the `undefined` value. If `undefined` is being overwritten, you can compare to e.g. `void 0` instead.

Comment: Previous rantish comment aside, this will "protect" the given code in question (so +1), although I prefer the solutions given by James Allardice or Frédéric Hamidi. Best yet, though, IMOHO, would be to remove the offending code ..

Comment: Unfortunately, it currently breaks in one of the dependencies that expects undefined not to have been overwritten. So I have no control over the way the test is performed anyway. And one might argue that I should not be using the dependency in this case, but I don't have the power to take these sort of decisions.

Comment: @JamesAllardice JSLint is one man's opinion on coding practices. If the warning bothers you then use [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) instead and turn off the specific warning.

Comment: @jbabey - I know, I wasn't saying that I agreed with the warning. But many people do rely on JSLint to give confidence in code or to enforce a coding style. But personally, I quite like that `x === void 0` is much quicker to type than `typeof x === "undefined"!